# Character column with floats does not convert to numeric

Tags: r, floating-point, type-conversion, character

I have two variables of which the `str()` is listed below. I have tried everything to convert these columns to numeric, but they will not budge.

```
 $ ASKPRICE_B_B                  : atomic  4,47 4,49 4,47 4,36 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "ASK PRICE_B_B"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%9s"
 $ BIDPRICE_B_B                  : atomic  4,4 4,39 4,33 4,29 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "BID PRICE_B_B"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%9s"
```

I have tried:

```
df$ASKPRICE_B_B <- as.numeric(as.character(df$ASKPRICE_B_B))
```

tried:

```
df$ASKPRICE_B_B <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", df$ASKPRICE_B_B)))
```

tried:

```
df$ASKPRICE_B_B <- sub(",", ".", df$ASKPRICE_B_B)
```

Mostly giving the error:

`Error: unexpected numeric constant in "X1809$ASKPRICE_B_B"`

I tried many other things but I cannot figure out what is going wrong..

I think it has something to do with the float being separated with a comma instead of a dot. Somehow I have not even been able to replace the comma with a dot.

Comment: How are you importing the data? Have you tried fixing the problem at import, with something like a `dec = ","` argument to `read.table` or `read.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`as.numeric((gsub(",", ".", df$ASKPRICE_B_B)))`

**PS:** As suggested by @Gregor, you could set the right character used in the file for decimal points (here, `dec = ","`) while importing your data.

Comment: `gsub` returns a character always, so your `as.character` won't do anything.

Comment: You're right, I wrote my answer too quickly. Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

. is a regex character. You need to escape them using \ or fixed = TRUE. Try.

```
df$ASKPRICE_B_B <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(df$ASKPRICE_B_B), fixed = TRUE))
```